# About Scoped Slots in vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I'm learning vuejs and reading about 'Slots'. 
I have understood it, how to use it. 
But I still have a concern about 'Scoped Slots' and I will talk about it with the code I have taken from vue documentation.

**Here is the code**

```html
/* this is child component */
<span>
  <slot v-bind:user="user">
    {{ user.lastName }}
  </slot>
</span>
```

```html
/* father component */
<current-user>
  <template v-slot:default="slotProps">
    {{ slotProps.user.firstName }}
  </template>
</current-user>
```

**My question:**

the code above make 'user' available to the slot content in the parent. 
That means the 'data' attribute in the child component will be as follows:

```js
data(){
  return {
     user: {
       firstName: 'fname',
       lastName: 'lname'
     }
  }
}
```

ok, I understood this part and practiced with it. But what if I change the 'data' attribute to:

```js
data(){
  return {
     firstName: 'fname',
     lastName: 'lname'
  }
}
```

I still don't know how to work with the 'Scoped Slots' in the above case (without the 'user').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your original code:

```html
<slot v-bind:user="user">
```

It's potentially confusing because there are two things called `user` here. The `v-bind:user` part is going to create a `user` property within the `slotProps` object. The other part, `="user"`, just assigns a value to that property. The fact that this value is also coming from a property called `user` makes this example somewhat difficult to follow.

For your second example, you could maybe do something like this:

```html
<slot v-bind:user="{ firstName, lastName }">
```

Note that `{ firstName, lastName }` is a shorthand for `{ firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName }`. It's just creating an object with two properties. The values for those two properties are coming from your `data`.

Again this is creating a property called `user` within the `slotProps` but this time the value is an object that is being created on the fly.

Comment: I have tried your solution and succeeded. Thank you.